# Xamarin.Forms only showing first cell of a grid

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to display an object in a grid using data binding. For some reason Only one Row of the grid is being displayed per entry. I know the data binding works, because if I comment out the first row of each grid it then displays the second row. Below is a sample of the relevant code, as well as a screenshot displaying the issue.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Game_Tracker.ViewModels;assembly=Game Tracker"
             x:Class="Game_Tracker.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:OpponentItemVm/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="OpponentList" ItemsSource="{Binding OpponentItems }">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame BorderColor="Black" 
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               Padding="0">
                            <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name: "/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OpponentFullName}"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Email: "/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OpponentEmail}"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Phone: "/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OpponentPhone}"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Address: "/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OpponentAddress}"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Id: "/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OpponentId}"/>
                                </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
    
    

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Game_Tracker
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Opponent.cs

```
using System;

namespace Game_Tracker.Models
{
    public class Opponent
    {
        public int OpponentId { get; set; }
        public string OpponentFName { get; set; }
        public string OpponentLName { get; set; }
        public string OpponentAddress { get; set; }
        public string OpponentPhone { get; set; }
        public string OpponentEmail { get; set; }

        public string OpponentFullName => $"{OpponentFName} {OpponentLName}";

        public Opponent(int opponentId, string opponentFName, string opponentLName, 
            string opponentAddress, string opponentPhone, string opponentEmail)
        {
            this.OpponentId = opponentId;
            this.OpponentFName = opponentFName;
            this.OpponentLName = opponentLName;
            this.OpponentAddress = opponentAddress;
            this.OpponentPhone = opponentPhone;
            this.OpponentEmail = opponentEmail;


        }
    }
}
```

OpponentItemVM.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Game_Tracker.Models;

namespace Game_Tracker.ViewModels
{
    public class OpponentItemVm
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Opponent> OpponentItems { get; set; }

        public OpponentItemVm()
        {
            OpponentItems = new ObservableCollection<Opponent>();
            OpponentItems.Add(new Opponent(1, "Jim", "Jimson",
                "123 Fake Street", "(123)123-4567", "Jim@Fake.com" ));
            OpponentItems.Add(new Opponent(2, "Ken", "Kensington",
                "123 False Street", "(123)123-4567", "Ken@Fake.com" ));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of XAML project]

Comment: try specifying an overall height value for the grid or frame

Comment: I was under the impression that grid and frame didn't have explicit height properties? Unless I am missing something.

Comment: all VisualElements have a HeightRequest property.  I suspect that the layout engine just doesn't have enough data to correctly calculate the height of each row.  Adding a HeightRequest (or you could use RowHeight on the LIstView) gives it additional data to help it make the correct calculation.

Comment: Using RowHeight on the list view worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I agree with Jason.However, the best practice is that you just add `HasUnevenRows` to `True` and let unset the `RowHeight` property which will automatically set the row height to fit content like below:

```
   <ListView x:Name="OpponentList" ItemsSource="{Binding OpponentItems }"  HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame BorderColor="Black" 
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           Padding="0"
                           
                           >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name: "/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OpponentFullName}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Email: "/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OpponentEmail}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Phone: "/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OpponentPhone}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Address: "/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OpponentAddress}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Id: "/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OpponentId}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Official reference docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.hasunevenrows?view=xamarin-forms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#row-height